# Export Catalog with images to PDF (using asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, pdf

I'm working on a project that needs to export a serie of pages to a single PDF, it will have different pages, will be something like a PDF catalog.

In the past I already worked with reporting services using .rdl files to create the templates and export to PDF reports, invoices, etc. However this time it is a bit different, it will have different pages.

1. Cover
2. Big image (full page)
3. Index
4. Catalog (with images 2 or 3 images per line with descriptions in the bottom of each image) with a special header
5. Catalog same as 4 but the header will be different 
   will repeat 4-5 as many times as categories
6. Big image (full page)
7. Another image or other content
8. Back cover

Since it is not a typical Header/Report(body)/Footer thing I'm not sure what is the best way to go, I know there are a lot of ways of doing it but before I start I better see what options are there and what is the best way to do it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would take a look at the [ITextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) library

Comment: Was looking at it, looks good, but the report is quite designed, lots of details, not sure if I will be able to do it all through code from scratch, I might need to create some type of template first... Or do different report files and merge them by the end.  anothe thing I saw but I'm not too sure of how far i can go is to modify the "InDesign" file template to creat it from there...